# Where function ignoring Nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I am trying to use the where function while ignoring Nan, I do not wish to drop or replace the Nans.

Here a toy data set:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
                 'A':[8,39,40,52],
                 'B':[8,39,np.nan,50],
                 })
```

Which gives:

```
    A    B
0   8   8.0
1   39  39.0
2   40  NaN
3   52  50.0
```

Desired result:

```
    A   B       check
0   8   8.0     True
1   39  39.0    True
2   40  NaN     Nan
3   52  50.0    False
```

I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
df = ((np.where(df['A']== df['B'], True, False))| df.isnull())
```

Comment: `where` is only as good as boolean condition array, `df['A']== df['B']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have mask where there are `NaN` in either of the columns then insert `np.nan` there using boolean masking.

```
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)
df['check'] = df['A'].eq(df['B'])
df.loc[m, 'check'] = np.nan # This would upcast bools to floats.
```

One workaround is to make `check` column's dtype as `object` using `Series.astype`.

```
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)
df['check'] = df['A'].eq(df['B'])
df['check'] = df['check'].astype(object)
df.loc[m, 'check'] = np.nan

   A     B  check
0   8   8.0   True
1  39  39.0   True
2  40   NaN    NaN
3  52  50.0  False
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do a `where`:

```
df['A'].eq(df['B']).where(df[['A','B']].notna().all(1))
```

But then this would <del>downcast</del> upcast `True, False` to `float`.

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks for pointing that out. Updated.

Comment: Using `astype(object)` protects against the casting `df.assign(check=(df['A'] == df['B']).astype(object).mask(df.isnull().any(1)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
#Using df.apply
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({
             'A':[8,39,40,52],
             'B':[8,39,np.nan,50],
             })
def check(df):

    if not (pd.isnull(df["A"]) or pd.isnull(df["B"])):
        if df["A"]==df["B"]:
            return "True"
        else:
            return "False"
    else:
        return "Nan"
df["check"]=""
df["check"]=df.apply(check,axis=1)
print(df)

output:
    A     B  check
0   8   8.0   True
1  39  39.0   True
2  40   NaN    Nan
3  52  50.0  False
```